# Graph outdegree help C++

Tags: c++, graph

first time posting here.
I am working on a graph function and have ran into some errors writing my function to find the outdegree of a graph.
Code:

> inside my dgraph.cpp file

```
int dgraph::findOutDegree(char)
{
 for (int i = 0; i < countUsed; i++) // enters a loop starting at 0 and going to countUsed(20)
  {
    if (Gtable[i].vertexName == vertexName) // if the Vertexname at position i = the vertex I am looking for
     {
      return Gtable[i].outDegree; // return that position as the outdegree
     }
  else
    {
        //not sure what to do for this part of the code
    }
  }
 return -1; // vertex was not found
}
```

I get an error "dgraph.cpp:70: error: âvertexNameâ was not declared in this scope" how do i fix it?
Not sure if i provided enough info to answer my question. Can provide more information if needed, like i said first time posting on here.

Comment: You have two items called vertexName: one is a variable and the other is a member variable.  One of them has either not been declared or is not in scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have never declared the variable `vertexName`. It should probably be either your class variable or an argument to the method. I.e,

```
int dgraph::findOutDegree(char)
```

should be

```
int dgraph::findOutDegree(char vertexName)
```

Comment: Thank you. It was able to compile now =)